# What is K2 BlackPearl? What is the use of It?

Tags: k2, k2-blackpearl

I am new to K2  blackpearl. can any one tell me what is it? How does it makes business process easy? what about the future benefits of K2 blackpearl (as a career)?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

K2 Blackpearl is just a piece of software thats is used for building process-driven applications.

> How does it makes business process easy?

It makes things easy because the so called 'Wizard' allows for a user to click their way through setup with minimal typing. K2 takes care of everything.

For an extensive overview of what it is used for, look at this article:

[Blackpearl Overview](http://www.imagetechsys.com/K2/K2-Business-Process-Management-Blackpearl-Overview.html)

Answer (score 2):

Blackpearl is part of the K2 offering made of:

- Blackpearl
- Smartforms
- a few additional parts for Sharepoint, SAP, etc...

Blackpearl is the workflow engine part. 
It takes care of the 'background' work of your business process.

What makes Blackpearl 'easy' are the provided Wizards as mentioned already but also the fact that you can use SmartObjects. This is a proprietary level of abstraction that allows you developing BPMS without any programming.

Blackpearl makes it very easy to interact with a database such as MsSQL, Oracle, etc.. but also with LDAP/Active Directories, Web Services, etc...
You *may* develop using .Net if you wish but Blackpearl allows going quite far without having to type a single line of code.